# Mandatory dynamic fields with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to create dynamic mandatory fields for product submitting to DB, I found a solution to create "static fields" mandatory, but I can't figure how to do the same with fields which are created depending on user choice.

This is how I handle the dynamic form creation

```js
var $input_DVD = $('<input id="dvd" input type="text" name="dvd" class="input" placeholder="Size in Mb"/>');
var $input_Book = $('<input id="book" input type="text" name="book" class="input" placeholder="Weight in Kg"/>');
var $input_FurnitureHeight = $('<input id="furnh" input type="text" class="input" name="furnh" placeholder="Height in Cm"/>');
var $input_FurnitureWidth = $('<input id="furnw" input type="text" class="input" name="furnw" placeholder="Width in Cm"/>');
var $input_FurnitureLength = $('<input id="furnl" input type="text" class="input" name="furnl"  placeholder="Length in Cm"/>');


$(document).ready(function() {
    $('select#Product_Type').on('change', function() {
        $('#container').remove();

        var val = $(this).val()
        $container = $('<fieldset id="container" class="inner" ></fieldset>');//  

        if (val == "Dvd")$input_DVD.appendTo($container);
        if (val == "Book") $input_Book.appendTo($container);
        if (val == "Furniture"){
            $input_FurnitureHeight.appendTo($container);
            $input_FurnitureWidth.appendTo($container);
            $input_FurnitureLength.appendTo($container);
        }
        $container.insertAfter($(this)).val();
    })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>Insert your data</h1>
    <form method="post" action="add_product.php">
        <input type="hidden" name="submitted" value="true" />


    <fieldset id="product_list">
        <legend>New Product</legend>
        <label>SKU:<input type="text" name="ID"/></label>
        <label>Name:<input type="text" name="name"/></label>
        <label>Price:<input type="text" name="price"/></label>
        <label>Product Type</label>
        <select id="Product_Type" name="prtype">
            <option style="display: none;" selected>Select product type</option>
            <option value="Dvd">DVD</option>
            <option value="Book">Book</option>
            <option value="Furniture">Furniture</option>
        </select>
    </fieldset>
</div>
    <br  />
    <input type="submit" name="add" value="Add" onClick="window.location.reload()"/>
</form>
```

Comment: what do you mean by mandatory?

Comment: Why can't you just use `required` ? Not really clear what problem is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if you want to make something mandatory ("required") then add the [required](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input#attr-required) attribute to each field that is required. to make it work on a `select` you need to assign first or selected option to have a empty value: `value=""`

```
<form>
  <input type="text" required>

  <select required>
    <option value="" selected>Select product type</option>
    <option value="Dvd">DVD</option>
  </select>
</form>
```

btw, your `onClick="window.location.reload()"` is wrong, html attributes should be all lowercase unless you use react (which bends the rules)

...and styling `<options>` have no visual effect so that can be removed (`style="display: none"`)

also worth reading up on [constraint validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/HTML/HTML5/Constraint_validation)

Answer (score 1):

Use required for the madatory fields for the inserted string to be mandatory same thing applies. A better solution is o hide the inputs instead of inserting theres an example below. But what i will say is you have to watch the select input and hide all elements but the one selected

```js
$('#select').change(function() {
  var value = $(this).val()
  // Hide the other inputs
  $('option').each(function(){
  console.log($(this).val())
    $('#'+$(this).val()).hide();
  })
  // Show the input
  $('#'+value).show()
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="form">
  <input type="text" name="name" placeholder="Enter name" required>
  <select id="select">
    <option selected>Default option</option>
    <option value="Book" placeholder="Enter Book Name">Book</option>
  </select>
  <!-- Dont insert html with strings its a bad option hide the input instead -->
  <input type="text" id="Book" name="Book" hidden required>
  <input type="submit" />
</form>
```